# Autoscaling workers for delayed_job in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, backgroundworker, delayed-job

I've been using [collectiveidea](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job)'s fork of delayed_job as a gem in my Rails 3 app, and it's working fine.  I'm now looking for a solution to autoscale workers, specifically for Heroku.  I've given [pedro](https://github.com/pedro/delayed_job)'s fork a try but since it's written for Rails 2, using it throws lots of errors and warnings about deprecated methods and I haven't been able to get it to work successfully.

Is there a working solution for Rails 3 delayed_job with autoscaling workers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [workless](https://github.com/lostboy/workless), it's one of the only Rails3 worker autoscalers I've seen at this point.

Comment: Good suggestion.  I have been using workless for a bit in production, which I found after posting this question.  I've had no problems with it scaling up and shutting down a worker.  One caveat is that it will scale up only one worker for multiple jobs and process jobs sequentially rather than concurrently, but that's fine with me.

Answer (score 2):

Specifically for heroku, check out "HireFire - The Heroku Worker Manager" and hirefireapp service:

- https://github.com/meskyanichi/hirefire - open source
- http://hirefireapp.com/ - service in public beta now

Answer (score 0):

I've started working on a gem called [Komodo](https://github.com/thetron/komodo) to perform that very same task for un upcoming project at work. However, since we've only just started on the project, the gem is still very, *very* early - and untested.

I should see some consistent updating over the next couple of weeks though - would certainly appreciate any feedback or contributions! :)