# Rails 3: Autoscaling workers in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

What's the best way to autoscale workers in Heroku using Rails 3?

Comment: Check out * https://github.com/meskyanichi/hirefire - open source * http://hirefireapp.com/ - service in public beta now

Answer (score 2):

[This branch of delayed_job works pretty well.](https://github.com/pedro/delayed_job/tree/autoscaling)  It's really easy to implement if you're already using delayed_job in your app.

Edit:
[This gem should work in Rails 3](https://github.com/lostboy/workless) according to [this S.O thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236565/autoscaling-workers-for-delayed-job-in-rails-3)

Comment: Personally, I am not sure but I updated the answer with one that should work in Rails 3.

Comment: Note that Workless works on Cedar, while I don't believe the HireFire gem does.

Comment: I've tried [Workless](https://github.com/lostboy/workless). So far, so good. Works out of the box, with about zero config, and it's free. Very pleased, thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

You could adapt [this gem](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-autoscale) to detect when there's a lot of jobs and then scale it up.

Answer (score 0):

I am using workless gem, and it seems reliable for my dev purpose (scale between 0 and 1 worker)
I tried to use heroscale.com but the service is down for 2 month and I am not that confident with leaving my heroku credentials on such a young service

Answer (score 0):

[HireFire](https://github.com/meskyanichi/hirefire) is a great gem for 'scaling' workers- allows you to only pay for the exact amount (to the second) of work that needs to be done.  Works with delayed job and rescue.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [guv](https://github.com/flowhub/guv) which is open source. If you don't want to run it yourself, you can also use it [as an add-on](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/guvscale)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options. Heroku exposes the [Platform API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference) which you can use to scale up and down. Alternatively, there are a few [Heroku Addons](https://elements.heroku.com/addons#dynos) that can solve this problem for you. I use this [heroku autoscaling](https://dynoscale.net) addon for my projects.